# How i can best deploy an application from git to forge that requires an entry in the .env file?

Tags: git, environment-variables, laravel-forge

I have a Laravel app that uses a socialite custom provider to connect an oAuth2.0 API.

I would like to use Forge to deploy this simply, on the regular.I cannot however, figure out how to do it, as there is a required entry in the .env file for the Socialite provider. If it is not there, it fails.

I have tried using the inbuilt environment editor, but you can only do it once it has been pushed to forge.

Now obviously I shouldn't commit my .env file, so what is the best way around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok after much deliberation, I tried without installing composer dependencies and forge just created the entries in the ENV file automatically....err I feel outsmarted, but in a nice way. Thanks forge! :)